Calculate thermal efficiency of turbo vs NA engine using Otto cycle
Otto cycle

1. Naturally Aspirated Engine
We’ll use the following values:
T1=300K
​T2=754K
T3=1754K
T4=698K
e=1- (T4-T1)/(T3-T2) =60.2%
2. Turbocharged Engine
For the turbocharged engine, we’ll use:
T1=350K
T2=879K
T3=1879K
T4=748K
e=60%
Why I get same efficiency, which temperatures I choose wrong, what will be correct temperatures choice from real case?

Because you are using an expression based on the Carnot cycle ie max possible. Run an engine NA which you can then turbo charge to see what happens. And what is the "previous example"?

@SolarMike what previous example? tell me real temperatures that I must plug in?

You quote the previous example, see the text in your own question: "Naturally Aspirated Engine We’ll use the following values from the previous example:"

@SolarMike sorry this is from chatgpt example

I suggest you need to read books by Chapman, Judge, Cummins, Rogers & Mayhew to get an understanding of the processes and enthalpy. Those books are better than ChatGPT based on what you post.

So T1 for the turbo engine is intake after the turbo - but what about an intercooler ?

@SolarMike from this equation I dont see how turbo increase eta, intercooler reduce temperature but not to atmosperic tem. like in NA

Then find the explanation of the expression you use to calculate the efficiency and see what it means, so you can then compare to a real engine.
